# Splitting a text file into an array in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Hi I have seen many examples for splitting the lines but how can I split lines in txt file if some lines contain \n in their string.

Suppose I have a file with following lines:

```
"Test \n Line1"
"Test Line 2"
```

How can I split these two lines as :

```
ResultArray = ['Test \n Line1', 'Test Line 2']
```

Comment: Does the original text file contain the quotes? And can the text file have text like this: `"string 1" "string 2"` or will there always be a `\n` between the lines? (As well as sometimes within a specific string.)

Comment: No the string contains \n. It does not contain any quotes. And the strings will be in the next line always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this one,

In your text file just put your strings each in newline without that quotes. After that, your text file should be look something like this,

```
Test \n Line1
Test Line 2
```

And where you are reading your text file write

```
var ResultArray;
fs.readFile('test', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    ResultArray = contents.split("\n");
});
```

Now your resultArray will look like

```
ResultArray =  ['Test \\n Line1', 'Test Line 2' ];
```

Don't worry that your `resultArray` contains items with `double \\n`. When you try to get some value from your array it will have only `one \` like when you do `console.log(resultArray[0])` your output will be like

```
Test \n Line1
```